# Issue with joomla 1.5 (error 500 when I access to item of type different than Articles » Articles

Tags: joomla, http-headers

Someone gives me a web page based in joomla 1.5.

The webpage has many menu, but in the "user menu" in the front-end when the user selects any menu item of that menu, the webpages returns a blank page (error 500 in saw in headers).

I think that is issue of permission.

The webpage has 755 for every folders, and 644 for every files.

Also I have checked that menu items of type "Articles » Articles" works ok, but other of tupe "JForms » Form", "Articles » Article / Form", does not works.

What can i do in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Turn the errors on in Global configuration, if you can find further info.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

The issue was because the machine has not internet conection to outside, so, internally the server had a timeout in the process. For this reason, the server returns 500 error.

*When a page was consulted (of that type of article), the server try to connecto to feedburner.com for example.